# storing url before going to new page with nuxt-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

I want to store my url when I am on the main page `/main` in the browser before going to another page using `nuxt-link`. This is my `nuxt-link`:

```
<NuxtLink
  :to="`/search?param={number}`"
  @click.native="assignAddress"
>
  SEARCH
</NuxtLink>
```

And this is the method that is triggered by clicking on `nuxt-link`:

```
assignAddress() {
  localStorage.setItem("address", `${this.$route.path}`);
},
```

The issue is that it saves `/search` in the browser. What I think happens is that the method `assignAddress` is being triggered after nuxt changes the page!

How can I store the url in the browser first and then change the page so in my browser I store `/main` instead of `/search`?

Comment: What is the end goal for this? You probably don't need to store it, especially if it's to go back on the previous page or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned above, you can indeed use some router guards.
I do prefer to use `beforeRouteEnter` over `beforeRouteLeave` because I feel like the [resolution flow](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow) may be less bug-prone if my targeted component is properly mounted, hence no bug during the component transition.

Here how this would look like code-wise

`/pages/search-page.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>This is the search page</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchPage',
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    console.log('came from', from)
    localStorage.setItem('address', from.path)
    next()
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@seyet how about you try setting it within the `beforeRouteLeave` navigation guard.

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  // called when the route that renders this component is about to
  // be navigated away from.
  // has access to `this` component instance.
}
```

Link to docs found [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Just make sure to call `next()` once you're finished.